# Converting PF1 adventure to pf2 - loot?

Tags: conversion, treasure, pathfinder-2e

I'm wondering in regards to loot and the transition from pf1 to pf2.

In pf2 the focus went from gp to sp I'm not sure if the loot needs to be downgraded when I convert an adventure.

As example The adventure Hollows last hope leads adventurerrs on the path from lvl 1 to lvl 2-3. During one of the encounters (not the boss encounter!) th group can find a treasure consisting of a ruby (worth 300 gp but can be used on a magic item in the dungeon and thus lost) and 62 gp.

As this is not the only treasure they find (a few magic arrows, rings,... and mastercraft weaponry).

I'm wondering if that should be the same in pf2.

Thus my question: When converting pf1 adventurs to pf2 is there anything to keep in mind in regards to loot (downgrading or upgrading it in terms of worth)?

Answer (score 2):

### Converting Pathfinder Adventures from 1e to 2e requires *heavy* loot alteration

The loot system in Pathfinder 2e is completely revised. For example, a common fairly low level [mithral](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/EQUIPMENT/SPECIAL-MATERIALs/#Mithral) chain shirt costs a bit over 1000g in 1e.

The [same item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=144), low grade (don't even consider high grade for now) is a *level 12 item* worth over 1600g in a system where each gold is worth more.

There a large number of other examples including Adamantine and enhancement bonuses being completely revised as well as a large number of items simply not existing (yet) in the new system. Any loot in the conversion must be hand-altered to be [level appropriate for that encounter](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=572) in Pathfinder 2e.

There are [multiple threads on the community forums](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2val0?Converted-Rise-of-the-Runelords-Playtest) about AP conversion for more information.